# Loading KVM AMD module fails

Tags: 11.10, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, kernel-modules, qemu

I want to use QEMU+KVM on Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric but `virt-manager` warns that KVM is not loaded and performance will suffer.

The problem may depend on the fact that

```
sudo modprobe kvm-amd
```

fails with error

```
FATAL: Error inserting kvm_amd (/lib/modules/3.0.0-13-generic/kernel/arch/x86/kvm/kvm-amd.ko): Operation not supported
```

eventhough

```
sudo modprobe kvm
```

succeeds without warnings. What is wrong?

Answer (score 7):

It may be that the AMD CPU doesn't have the virtualization extensions

```
egrep '(vmx|svm)' --color=always /proc/cpuinfo
```

Since you have an AMD, if you don't have `svm` in there, then you can't load `kvm-amd`.

It might be disabled in the BIOS, many vendors disable it by default.